# Flutter/Dart - Android Manifest Permissions crashes App upon first Build

Tags: flutter, dart, build, android-manifest, android-permissions

There's something weird happening upon the first build of my app within Android Studio. After accepting "allow" for the following permissions, the app crashes and doesn't finish loading onto my phone.

```
Allow YourApp to access photos and media on your device?
Allow YourApp to record audio?
```

But when I try the build again it's fully loaded and works fine the second time.

Here's what's in my AndroidManifest.xml;

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

And here's where I'm asking for record permission;

```
_init() async {
try {
  setState(() {
    stopButton = false;
    playButton = false;
    recButton = true;
  });
  if (await FlutterAudioRecorder.hasPermissions) {
    String customPath = '/flutter_audio_recorder_';
    io.Directory appDocDirectory;
    if (io.Platform.isIOS) {
      appDocDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    } else {
      appDocDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    }
    customPath = appDocDirectory.path +
        customPath +
        DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    _recorder = FlutterAudioRecorder(customPath,
        audioFormat: AudioFormat.AAC, sampleRate: 44100);

    await _recorder.initialized;
    var current = await _recorder.current(channel: 0);

     setState(() {
      _current = current;
      _currentStatus = current.status;
    });
  } else {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
        new SnackBar(content: new Text("You must accept permissions")));
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
 }
}
```

Any idea why it's crashing that first time I try to build?

Comment: Manifest alone isn't enough to to obtain permissions since Android 6 (API 23) I believe. You need to ask for permission (which you say you are doing), the process is async so I'm guessing the app is crashing because you aren't waiting for the permission or you aren't handling it right... but that is just a guess, please include code of how you are asking for permissions.

Comment: OK. I've edited the OP to include the code where I'm asking for permission to record audio.

Comment: Ok, now for some more guesswork... I'm guessing you have that init() inside the initState() of a statefullWidget, something like this `@override void initState() { super.initState(); init(); ...`. You can't have awaits inside the initState. If you must place it there then at least start it as a new future, like so: `@override void initState() { super.initState(); new Future.delayed(Duration.zero,() async { await init(); }) ...` Also no way for the user to request permissions manually or any kind of message before the the request is made(explain to the user what and why you need it beforehand).

Comment: That didn't work.  Here's what I replaced the record audio _init() code with;   @override
  void initState() {super.initState(); 
    new Future.delayed(Duration.zero,() async { await _init(); }); } Do you think the problem lies with the permissions for photos and video instead?

Comment: Can you suggest another place I can put the _init()?